# install pymongo3-1.9b1 on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, pymongo

Based on manual, I have tried the following two methods to install pymongo in ubuntu 11.0
without success. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Method One:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Downloads/pymongo3-1.9b1$ sudo python3.2 setup.py install
Extracting in /tmp/tmp206r5e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Downloads/pymongo3-1.9b1/distribute_setup.py", line 139, in use_setuptools
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "/home/user/Downloads/pymongo3-1.9b1/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/user/Downloads/pymongo3-1.9b1/distribute_setup.py", line 125, in _do_download
    _build_egg(egg, tarball, to_dir)
  File "/home/user/Downloads/pymongo3-1.9b1/distribute_setup.py", line 98, in _build_egg
    tar = tarfile.open(tarball)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/tarfile.py", line 1744, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

Method Two:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Downloads/pymongo3-1.9b1$ sudo easy_install pymongo3
Searching for pymongo3
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymongo3/
Reading http://github.com/agronholm/mongo-python-driver-py3k
Best match: pymongo3 1.9b1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pymongo3/pymongo3-1.9b1.tar.gz#md5=6c65dcad8674f37ffc8bc3d6e1fd4155
Processing pymongo3-1.9b1.tar.gz
Running pymongo3-1.9b1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-Iv0ZIq/pymongo3-1.9b1/egg-dist-tmp-sUlwd7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute==0.6.15', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1906, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1887, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1910, in <lambda>
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 363, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 603, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 633, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 823, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1100, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1089, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 29, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 70, in run
    return func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 150
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file setup.py on line 150, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
user@ubuntu:~/Downloads/pymongo3-1.9b1$
```

I found that I have the zlib installed on my machine

```
user@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 242 not upgraded.
```

I have used the following method to install python 3.2

```
1> tar -xvf Python-3.2.tgz && cd Python-3.2/
2> ./configure
3> make
4> sudo make altinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

The culprit for the second error is the line:

```
maintainer="Alex Grönholm",
```

which uses an umlaut but the file encoding isn't declared and defaults to ASCII.

Grab the package source using

```
easy_install --editable --build-directory ~/Desktop pymongo3
```

then edit `~/pymongo3/setup.py` and fix / delete the offending line. You should be able to install using

```
easy_install ~/Desktop/pymongo3
```

The installation proceeds past parsing `setup.py` for me, then crashes on a module introduced in Python 3. (I only have 2.7 handy.)

You should also at least report this as a bug.

Comment: I have seen that easy_install pymongo3 should NOT be used for installing pymongo for python3x. Thus, we should focus on how to fix the first problems.

Comment: @q0987: The first problem sounds like it's caused by you not having setuptools / distribute installed. Where have you seen that you shouldn't use `easy_install`? I can't find such a claim and it sounds bizarre to me considering the package has a dependency on setuptools.

Comment: If you use easy_install to install pymongo3 for python3 without root permission, you will find out that easy_install will try to change the content inside python2.x rather than python3.x

Comment: I'm confused. easy_install / distutils installers should, by default at least, install into the python they vere run with. If you have multiple versions of python installed, just make sure you're running the correct easy_install explicitly instead of relying on `$PATH`

Comment: The default python installed on ubuntu 10.04 or 11.04 is python 2.6 or 2.7 respectively. easy_install will trigger python 2x directly rather than using the p3.

Comment: You're supposed to install setuptools in your p3 instance, and then use the easy_install command from that, not the default one.